# query in sparql for protege

Tags: sparql, protege

I want write query that allow to display all comment of all class in protege
and other query to display specific comment
please ,Iwante the answer quickly as soon as possible .

Comment: It's kind of rude to demand a quick answer without trying to come up with something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query
`SELECT DISTINCT ?class ?comment
WHERE { [] a ?class.
        ?class rdfs:comment ?comment }`

Comment: This will display all classes with their comments